# How to set first TabBar selected programmatically on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitabbar

I have `UITabBar` in view which have 5 tabs. I am using `didSelectItem` delegate to open different view i.e. I am NOT using `TabBarController`.

My problem is on view load I need first tab get selected by default. Is there any property in TabBar which we can set to make it selected?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11201924/1463604

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This code will work `[tabBar setSelectedItem:[tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0]];`

Answer (score 4):

In swift if tabbar is used not tabbarcontroller set default select

```
var tabbar:CustomTabBar?//if declare like this
tabbar!.selectedItem = self.tabbar!.items![0] as? UITabBarItem
```

or

```
let tabbar = UITabBar()//if declare and initilize like this
tabbar.selectedItem = self.tabbar.items![0] as? UITabBarItem
```

Comment: It will crash and shows Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

set the 
tabbar.selectedItem=0; in the viewWillAppear so when ever the view appears it will select the first tab by default.

Comment: its not working...... [tabBar setSelectedItem:<#(UITabBarItem *)#>
I have used IB to create TabBar.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.tabBar setSelectedItem:self.tabBar.items[0]];
```

or

```
self.tabBar.selectedItem = self.tabBar.items[0];
```

The selectedItem property requires a TabBarItem and not an index. So provide the tabbaritem in index 0 for the first tab.

This is wrong then: `tabbar.selectedItem=0;`

You may select other tabs as well. Happy coding