# Programmatically changing the selected tab of tabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a basic project created in xcode as a "Tab Bar Application", What I would like is to have the application on load switch to the 2nd tab if BOOL x is true.

Right now I have: (located in FirstViewController.m in viewDidLoad)

```
if(x){
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
}
```

This causes the selected tab at the bottom of the page to highlight the 2nd tab, however the view remains that of the first tab.

How would I go about changing the view to that of the 2nd tab?

Comment: What you have is correct at the surface level.  I suspect something odd in the way your tab bar controller is set up. If your were to log the viewControllers property of your tab bar controller, do you see distinct view controllers?

Comment: Yes, if I log viewControllers I get back an array of the 3 Controllers in my project.

Comment: Okay, then if you log the selectedViewController property of your tab bar controller before and after the call to -setSelectedIndex:, are the controllers what you expect them to be, or does it stay the same?

Comment: The second one shows what I would expect, however before running setSelectedIndex it shows (null)

Comment: OK I did a little playing around. If I move the code into a button instead of viewDidLoad it works.  How would I get this to work within viewDidLoad?

Comment: Yeah, same philosophy here that I mentioned in my answer. I just noticed this comment. Long story short, I'm not sure you can. But you can get close...

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Well, I reproduced your issue, and solved it by moving the switching logic from -viewDidLoad to -viewDidAppear:. So basically, change:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Other code...
    if(x){
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
    }
}
```

to:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // Other code...
    if(x){
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
    }
}
```

Now, as to why this is the case, I can only guess, without more digging, that it has to do with the order things are initialized.  It is possible that your view controller's viewDidLoad is being called before the parent tab bar controller has finished its own initialization.  Holding off until your view has actually appeared ensures that everything is loaded and in a consistent state.

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I don't know why.. I put the same code [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]; within a function that is executed when a button is pressed. Do you have ideas?

Comment: @acecapades, you're saying the code _doesn't_ work when placed in a button handler?

Comment: @MattWilding I agree with you that it should work. well, at least in my program it doesn't. Weird. I'll check again, most likely there's something else that's wrong with my code.

Comment: here whats the value of x in if statement

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that you are working with a controller that is a subclass of the UITabBarController, you only need to set the selectedIndex property.

For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

I prefer to do this assignment in the viewDidLoad method so you can be guaranteed that only the view controller at the selected index is displayed. If you use the viewDidAppear function, you will occasion see the view controller at index 0 displayed briefly when the tab bar view loads before the one at index 1 is shown.

Comment: I tried many things. This one was the only one working, Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This would suffice:

`[tabBar setSelectedIndex:0];`

Answer (score 3):

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1]
[window addSubview:[tabBarController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I get window is undeclared, if i switch it up to self.window it errors out with "Request for member 'window' in something not a struct or union"

Comment: This code is intended to be run from the app delegate's -applicationDidFinishLaunching:. It won't work as-is from your view controller's implementation.

Comment: Thats my problem, this does need to run from a view controller. I've simplified the problem above, but I wont know weather or not I need to send them to the tab until some loading is done on that particular view.

Answer (score 2):

**For Swift 3.0**

```
if(x)
{ 
  self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1
}
```