# Selecting a tab bar item conditionally

Tags: ios

I want to select a tab programmatically from UITabBarItem.
I did some research on how to do this, and I got the answer like below:

```
  [self.parentViewController.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

However, it does not work. I did not call it from viewDidAppear function (as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750002/programmatically-changing-the-selected-tab-of-tabbarcontroller), since I need to call it somewhere else, conditionally. Does this code only work inside viewDidAppear function?
Here's screenshot of my storyboard.
I am calling this from a viewController marked by the red circle, and my UITabBarController is marked by yellow circle. Sorry for bad quality image.
The red circled class is part of a "facebook style side bar menu" implementation.
I am a newbie in iOS development, any help will greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: Are you using UITabBar as rootViewController ?

Comment: No, I use UINavigationController as a rootViewController, and then I have a UITabBarController that has a relationship segue to that UINavigationController.

Comment: You can call the `setSelectedIndex:` method on the tab controller from anywhere you have access to the tab controller.

Comment: try this `[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];`

Comment: yes you can use setSelectedIndex anywhere you want, it should work properly. Please explain your scenario in more detail.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma I added screenshot of my storyboard

Comment: @iEngineer still does not work :( thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: You are doing it wrong in storyboard. Make you UITabBarController as rootViewController and then put UINavigationBar as it's tabItems

Comment: what is the left most view in screenshot ?

Comment: @iEngineer it's RevealViewController, an API for facebook style side bar menu from http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/
The goal is to be able to navigate from side bar menu as well as the tab bar.

Comment: Alright, then i need more code to view where you calling your `setSelectedindex` and what is the exact scenario.

Comment: @iEngineer I accepted your answer, please see my comments. Thanks for the hints and guides! Really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is, whenever you using UITabBar in your application, design your application to use UITabBar as a rootViewController. You can select tabItem conditionally by coding

`[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];`

This will work anywhere.

Comment: Does that mean I don't need the UINavigationController? I cannot make it as rootViewController, the only choices are relationship segues or push and modal. Does this mean I did something wrong in other parts? Thank you beforehand.

Comment: why u using UINavigationController as rootViewController?, as per screenshot, you are calling the UINavigationController's view in UITabBar again.

Comment: I thought every time we use UITabBarController, we need a UINavigationController before the ViewController as a rootViewController. I can't set the UITabBar as rootViewController, only "relationship segues" or push/modal/custom available.

Comment: hey, the code works, and I accepted your answer since because of your answer I investigated more regarding rootViewController and where I call / access my tabBarController to call setSelectedIndex. 

What i did at the end is finding my tabBarController in my storyboard, and then calling setSelectedIndex on that one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

if your UITabBarController as rootViewController

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
```

Comment: Avoid using this snippet in your project:
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] ????];

Comment: @null why may i know the reason?

Comment: hmm, please note that I said AVOID, because you are abusing the design of your app.  check http://www.hollance.com/2012/02/dont-abuse-the-app-delegate/  and  http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html