# UITabbarController selectedIndex and selectedViewController do not work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I've tried to put following two lines into `- (void)viewDidLoad.`

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];
```

At that time, only Tabbar index to change 3 but View Controller remained at default view controller, mean 0. Is there any thing missing in my coding?

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750002/programmatically-changing-the-selected-tab-of-tabbarcontroller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution:** Try by moving your,

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];
```

portion of your code to UIVIewController's

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

I hope it will help you

**Reason:** You have to let your UIViewController to load fully first before you trigger an extra action on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this definitely it works:

```
 UINavigationController *nc = [[self.tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
id vc = [[nc viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
if ([vc isKindOfClass:[YourViewController class]])
{
    [[self appDelegate].tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
}
```